# Oracle versioned geodatabase feature class field value update on multiple versions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, versioning

I have an Oracle enterprise geodatabase with multiple versions.

In one field value of one point feature class I need to change all features within all versions.

I have more than 50 versions.

Is there any solution for this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 products.

Comment: You had an ArcPy tag but your question does not include any code or mention of using it so I have removed it.

Comment: Are you unwilling to reconcile and post all versions to the same state?  If you are willing to do that then the Reconcile Versions tool can post the edits of one version to all of the others.  If you are not willing, the best approach is to cycle through all versions using ListVersions in arcpy and setting up a versioned editor session for each.  You would have to manually handle the conflicts created in each version when you do reconcile and post any of them later.

Answer (score 1):

The supported mechanism would be to edit the version pinning the top of your state tree, but that will cause attribute conflicts with every row in every version unless you also apply that edit to every version. Then you could reconcile this 51st version and post the change.

For this particular case, it would be faster (and **risky**, and **unsupported**) to make the edit directly to ***both*** the business table ***and*** the Adds table using SQL.  This is more of an experts-only solution, so if you don't know **exactly** what that means, **you should not attempt it**. Instead contact Tech Support and ask for their guidance.  You should certainly make a ***full backup*** of the tables before attempting this solution.